# CakePHP : when I change controller Session is death

Tags: session, cakephp, authentication

```
var $name = 'Users';
var $components = array('Auth', 'Acl');


function beforeFilter(){
    //parent::beforeFilter();
    $this->Auth->userModel = 'User';      $this->Auth->allow('register','login','step2','TakeId');
}
function login(){
    if(!empty($this->data)){
        if($this->Auth->login()){
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Zalogowany!'));
            $this->redirect('/');
        } else {
            $this->User->invalidate('password', 'Haslo lub Login niepoprawny.!');
        }
    } 
}
function logout(){
    $this->Auth->logout();
    $this->redirect('/');
}
```

And f.e. when I create:

```
class UserregistersController extends AppController {

    var $name = 'Userregisters';
    var $components = array('Auth', 'Acl');


    public function beforeFilter()
    {
        $this->Auth->userModel = 'User';
        $this->Auth->allow('index','view','register','edit');

    }
}
```

Now, the main problem:

I want to read `$this->Session->read('Auth');` , when I put line link : 
website/NoExistController/page --> all fine but when 
website/Userregisters/page --> Session is Death, return false :)

Where is mistake? Any idea?

Thx :)

Comment: You mean `$this->Session->read('Auth');` returns false?? Are you logged in?

Comment: Maybe you want use `$this->Auth->user('id')` ? It will give you user id or false if user is not logged.

Comment: Yes but I'm logg in and return false... :(

Comment: @user2427678 maybe you messed up in AppController, make ACL tutorial from cakebook.